# Stopping Refresh Functionality Using clearInterval() in Angular 6 is not working?

Tags: typescript, angular6, clearinterval

I am implementing Refresh Functionality on a page where user has two option.
[Refresh  Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgxt4.png)

1. Refresh the page when you click on the Refresh button (straight forward)
2. Give user option to set Refresh Frequency (Option to refresh page after certain Interval)
   [Set Interval Refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Prz.png)

As you can see in the image there are different values for each interval which I am storing in following object like this.

```
timer: RefreshTimer[] = [
{value: 15000, time: '15 Sec'},
{value: 30000, time: '30 Sec'},
{value: 45000, time: '45 Sec'},
{value: 100000, time: '1 min'},
{value: null, time: 'Cancel'}];
```

I am using `setInterval()` to cal `refresh()` method as Shown below:

```
refresh() {
this.router.navigateByUrl('./views/refresh/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
  console.log(decodeURI(this.location.path()));
  this.router.navigate([decodeURI(this.location.path())]);
});}

refreshFrequency(time) {
     if(time === null){
        this.counter = 110;
     }
this.progressInterval = setInterval(() => {
  this.counter += 10;
  this.refresh();
  console.log('this.counter', this.counter);

  if(this.counter >= 100){
    clearInterval(this.progressInterval);
    console.log('cleaned and finished');
  }
},time);
```

}

Calling `setInterval()` Like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="timer" style="width: 10px;">
           <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
           <mat-select class="alarm-dropdown" trigger="alarmTrigger" #alarmSelect>
           <mat-option   *ngFor="let time of timer" 
                  (click)="refreshFrequency(time.value)" 
                  [value]="time.value">
              {{time.time}}
            </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

This is the behavior right now, `clearInterval()` is not working after I select `Cancel` from DDL.
1. [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCwJB.png)
2. [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Waswj.png)
3. [Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxYmu.png)

Thank you for the help.

### Edit: Here is the [SlackBitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwsvzb?file=app/form-field-overview-example.html) for it.

Comment: this.progressInterval always creates a new instance of an Interval. You need to seperate it so you don't loose your reference to the interval that is created

Comment: Seprate it from ? I have even at one point tried to nullify `this.postInterval` but it still didn't work.

Comment: Also, when I am omitting `this.refresh()` call form `setInterval()` it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timers can be helpful but are notorious for running wild, so use with caution. As long as you make sure you don't create more timers than you need, and that you don't loose track of existing ones you'll be okay. 
Something like this:

**Save your reference to your timer**

```
this.intervalReference = null;
```

**Isolate your logic for starting and cleaning up the timer. Make sure it only ever does one timer or your reference will be overwritten.**

```
refreshFrequency(time) {
    if (!this.intervalReference && time !== null) {
        console.log('Creating a timer. It will run every ' + (time / 1000) +  ' seconds');
        this.intervalReference = setInterval(() => {
            this.counter += 10;
            this.refresh();
            console.log('this.counter', this.counter);
            if (this.counter >= 100) {
                clearInterval(this.intervalReference);
                console.log('Timer stopped as expected');
                this.intervalReference = null;
            }
        }, time);
    } else if (time === null && this.intervalReference) {
        console.log('Stopping timer early.');
        clearInterval(this.intervalReference);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the refresh isn't working. [Changes I made to the Code](https://imgur.com/a/hVoczaX). [Console Output](https://imgur.com/a/a73aZUn)

Comment: I updated my answer. I misread your original code. The change you made created a method, this.startInterval(), but we weren't calling it.. it seem unnecessary at this point. so just remove it using my edits.

Comment: As soon as I am Canceling the refresh it is entering in some kind of loop. A nasty way `setInterval()` works.

Comment: [Slackbitz Working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwsvzb?file=app/form-field-overview-example.html)

Comment: No answers yet ?

Comment: Busy week. I got it working for you. Cleaning up the code now

Comment: I've updated my response. You should find that it works. The reason it wasn't is that you were passing "null" into setInterval, which means it basically runs as often as it can without any delay, other than finishing other scripts currently running.It would be like setTimeout(() => {}, 0)

Comment: So, it is not working in my case. You mentioned I am passing Null to setInterval() wha, what should I pass instead. Also, the behavior after applying your changes is like, I click on 15 sec from drop down -> It refreshes the page after 15 secs then it stops completely.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwsvzb-ccjmeu Here is my working example

Comment: Your Code works perfectly, but as soon as I am implementing it in my code something is screwing up the setInterval(). Currently, my code's behavior is like this -> Select 15 Secs from DDL -> Page Refreshes Every 15 Secs -> And if I don't select Cancel from DDL it stops refreshing perfectly after `this.counter = 100`. But When I hit Cancel It does nothing. I thing there is something messing up I still don't know what. But I will Mark you answer as it is 100% Correct. It's my code that's messing up.